# Passing php session variables to html page containing jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to pass a session variable to an html page as following :

```
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
header("location: main.html");
```

in main.html I have codes like this :

```
<?php 
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['login_user'];
?>
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('<?php echo $user_id; ?>');
    })
```

I expect to see an alert showing the user name - which is not happening. Any help about where it goes wrong?

Thanks

Comment: is your server parsing the main.html as a php page or is it treating it as an html and echoes the php to the browser? If its not treating as an html page then you might want to consider changing it to main.php and redirecting to main.php via header.

Comment: In the first page you call `session_start()`? Also, doesn't appear the username or the alert window?

Comment: It is anot a php page - it is html

Comment: Yes - I have not shown the session start in the first page but it is there

Comment: I think you have to rename 'main.html' to 'main.php', if your apache is not config to treat .html files as .php files

Answer (score 1):

I think you are messing up PHP and HTML.

You can only run `PHP` from `*.php` files. `*.html` files won't parse PHP (unless defined in your web server config). To make this work, rename `main.html` to `main.php`.

Also make sure that `session_start()` is on above every file that is using sessions.